# Change navbar CSS based on position on a single page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a single page HTML document that separates pages in  tags. The navbar's links connect to the sections with data-index and data-targets (targets being placed on the a href).

My question is how could I write a jquery script that changes the link to active if on the corresponding section?

Comment: Your question lacks details. Do you want to monitor which link was clicked, or the page scrolling? What have you tried so far? [Bootstrap Scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) seems similar to what you're asking for, but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @Blazemonger I've done something like the onclick below. But since im using jQuery onepage scroll, I need to add the active class to a link based off the corresponding section. eg. ( <section class="section active" data-index="1"></section> && the corresponding navbar link would be <a href="#" data-target="0" id="scroll">Page1</a> )

Answer (score 0):

You could use the inview jQuery plugin to add an "active" class when when the section is in the current viewport, and remove the "active" class on other links.

```
<a href="link1" id="link1" class="headerNavLink">Link 1</a>
<a href="link2" id="link2" class="headerNavLink">Link 2</a>
<a href="link3" id="link3" class="headerNavLink">Link 3</a>

<div class="section" data-link-id="link1"></div>
<div class="section" data-link-id="link2"></div>
<div class="section" data-link-id="link3"></div>
```

And the jquery would look like this:

```
$(".section").bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible) {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-link-id")).addClass("active");
  } else {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-link-id")).removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

For more information, check out https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview

Comment: Can't be with an onclick function. I'm using jquery one page scrolling, so I need it based off the section that the corresponding link gets the active class.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I've edited my answer with the a more relevant answer.